# read() on non-blocking socket without select for low-latency

Tags: c++, sockets, nonblocking

I have a separate thread reading from a non-blocking socket that I am ok with using as much CPU as necessary since low-latency is the most important aspect of the project.  Would it be faster to simply loop on a read() call than use a select() first to look for sockets that are readable?

Pseudo-code:

```
while (!finished) {

    int rc = read(socket, buf);
    if (rc > 0) {
        // process buf
    } else if (rc == 0) {
        // eof, reconnect to server
    } else if (errno == EGAIN) {
        // nothing to do, continue
    } else if (errno == ECONNREFUSED) {
        // connection refused, attempt connect again
    } else {
        // error not yet supported
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to do that ... why wouldn't you just do a blocking read?

Comment: Agreed. Putting the `read()` in a separate thread means that it can block without stalling the rest of the application. Non-blocking I/O is only necessary if the thread needs to do other things when data isn't available on the socket.

Comment: Part of the thought process was the spinning thread would be less likely to be context switched than a blocking socket waiting on a read or a non blocking socket using select.

Comment: A spinning thread isn't usually good for latency; it's likely to hold off other threads and slow down the rest of the system... and if you're running under a dynamically-prioritizing scheduler (e.g. the default scheduler for Linux), a spinning thread will have its priority dynamically reduced (so that other threads get first dibbs to the CPU) and that will actually increase latency for your thread.  So I agree with Barmar, you're better off using a blocking read (or even select() should be fine if you only have a few sockets registered in it).

Comment: Note that if you *really* want low latency, a better approach is to raise your thread or process's priority (e.g. under Linux, using sched_setscheduler() with a SCHED_RR or SCHED_FIFO argument), or even switching to a hard-real-time OS like Xenomai or VxWorks that will make latency guarantees for you.

Comment: Thread is also pinned to a dedicated core. Between that and no blocking read./select I hoped to keep thread from being switched out. Have experimented with rt kernels but that is still work on progress and would rather tune the app first.

Comment: Even though it has a dedicated core, there may be some global kernel locks that have to be acquired and released during each system call, which could impact threads on other cores. If you're worried about pages being swapped out, you could use mlock().

Answer (score 1):

No it wouldn't be faster, because you don't know when the data is going to arrive. So, either you will sleep for too long, which isn't faster, or you will sleep for too short, in which case you have to so it all again, which isn't faster, or you will get lucky and sleep for exactly the right time, which isn't faster and requires luck, or you won't sleep at all, which means you have to burn the CPU until the data arrives, which also isn't faster.

Comment: He never said anything about sleeping.

Comment: @Barmar Which comes under the heading of 'won't sleep at all'. What I have done here is enumerate *all* the possibilities (except using blocking mode, which is what he should be doing).

Comment: This thread has a dedicated core so burning cpu didn't seem to be an issue for me. Between that and not performing a select or blocking read I hoped to prevent the thread from being switched out.

Comment: It still won't be faster in any way you can actually measure. The limitation of the network bandwidth is orders of magnitude more significant than scheduling effects.